Transfering data with BigQuery tables
I have two BigQuery tables which have quite complicated and different schemas. What would be easiest way to get data from table A to table B. I tried INSERT INTO function but there are so many nested fields etc. so it gets pretty complex. So I'm trying to find another ways to solve issue

Have you tried insert select? Not sure BigQuery supports this, but might be worth a try if you have a complex select you can use that to do the insert with insert select.. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

When you say "Get data from Table A to Table B" I am interpreting that as append the rows in Table A to the existing content of Table B.  Using SQL INSERT INTO feels like the right way to go ... so let's look at the second part of the puzzle.   Table B (the target table) has a schema which describes the columns that are contained.  Table A also has a schema which describes the columns that are contained in it.  I am sensing that the schemas are dissimilar.  The puzzle now changes to creating a logical mapping from a row found in Table A to what you would desire to the corresponding row added to Table B.  There isn't an easy button to achieve that.  For each of the columns in the source table, you would have to ask and answer, what would the corresponding column or columns be in Table B.
Pretty much anything/everything can be done in BigQuery using the GoogleSQL language.  I hear you say it gets pretty complex ... and that may very well be the case.  However a solid study on arrays, STRUCT types and more is likely going to be beneficial.   Let me encourage you to "have a go".  As you then break your puzzle down into its constituent parts, my hope is that it will either get easier or repetitive (i.e. you will learn from a solution to one column how to approach the next column).  If you get really stuck, then you can always post a new StackOverflow question focusing on the very specific puzzle at hand.  Show some sample data, show what you have studied, show what you have tried and ask about specific interpretation.  StackOverflow is a GREAT place to look for answers to specific puzzles.  The more precise your question, the more likely it is to get attention.
